# render json not showing up in view on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, view, render

i have a form set to (remote: true to submit via ajax) where a user can input their email and zipcode. if the record gets validated by the model and saved successfully it triggers a javascript script that changes the dom accordingly to notify the user of success. However, if the record does not pass validation i want to get the errors via json back from the server and display them in a div near the form. However i cant get "else" part of the loop to work and get the json to render on the view.

in the chrome dev tools, when i try to submit a blank form, i get back a  status 200 and the response is

```
{"email":["is invalid"],"zip":["is not a number","is too short (minimum is 5 characters)"]}"
```

But how can i get these errors i get back from the controller to show up in the view?

Controller----------------------------------------------->

```
class EngagesController < ApplicationController

  def now
    @sub = Subscriber.new
  end

  def create
    @sub = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @sub.save
        format.html { render 'now', notice: 'User was successfully created.'     }
        format.js   {}
      else
        format.json { render :json => @sub.errors }
      end
    end
  end      


private
  def subscriber_params
    params.require(:engage).permit(:email, :zip)
  end

end
```

model---------------------------------------------------->

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]    {2,})\z/i
  validates :zip, numericality: {only_integer: true}, length: {minimum: 5}

end
```

Comment: Look forward `js.erb` stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rendering json, use

`format.js { render 'errors', errors: @subs.errors }`

And you need to write view file named errors.js.erb in which you will be displaying errors in the from using JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks, i tried making an error.js.erb as u suggested and it is running error.js.erb however i cant get the actual error message to show up. For example, in the error.js.erb i have the folloing code, "$('#subs').append( "<%= @sub.errors %>" )" i get a response from the server, "$('#subs').append( "#&lt;ActiveModel::Errors:0x86b91b8&gt;" )"

Comment: Where are the error messages stored after the failed validated from the model?  Also, in the answer you wrote what does the "errors: @subs.errors" part do? thanks again

Comment: Then you need to use @sub.errors.full_messages which gives you array. Just loop through and append it. Now `errors: @sub.errors` will pass variable `errors` to view file. So you can access it in errors.js.erb directly instead of accessing like @sub.errors. You can just use errors variable.